Slow and Inefficient Update Statement in Oracle
I have an update statement in Oracle that is intended to update tens of thousands of records in the "test_delete_me" table. However, the statement is extremely slow and inefficient.
This Oracle update statement recalculates the "ITEM" values in the "test_delete_me" table based on the row number sequence within each "ref_id" group, excluding rows with a specific status and null "ITEM" values.
Here is the update statement I'm using:
UPDATE test_delete_me a
SET ITEM = (
    SELECT row_num_seq - 1
    FROM (
        SELECT id, ref_id, ITEM, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ref_id ORDER BY id) AS row_num_seq
        FROM test_delete_me 
        WHERE 
            ref_id IN (
                SELECT ref_id
                FROM test_delete_me
                WHERE status = 3
                GROUP BY ref_id
                HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ITEM IS NULL THEN 1 END) > 2
            )
    )
    WHERE id = a.id -- Match the main table's ID with the subquery's ID
    AND row_num_seq NOT IN (1, 13) -- Exclude row_num_seq 1 and 13
)
WHERE EXISTS (
    SELECT 1
    FROM (
        SELECT id, ref_id, ITEM, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ref_id ORDER BY id) AS row_num_seq
        FROM test_delete_me 
        WHERE 
            ref_id IN (
                SELECT ref_id
                FROM test_delete_me
                WHERE status = 3
                GROUP BY ref_id
                HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ITEM IS NULL THEN 1 END) > 2
            )
    )
    WHERE id = a.id -- Match the main table's ID with the subquery's ID
    AND row_num_seq NOT IN (1, 13) -- Exclude row_num_seq 1 and 13
);

I've tried another approach but still encountered the same performance issue:
UPDATE test_delete_me a
SET ITEM = (
  SELECT row_num_seq - 1
  FROM (
    SELECT b.id, b.ref_id, b.ITEM, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.ref_id ORDER BY b.id) AS row_num_seq
    FROM test_delete_me b
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT ref_id
      FROM test_delete_me
      WHERE status = 3
      GROUP BY ref_id
      HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ITEM IS NULL THEN 1 END) > 2
    ) c ON b.ref_id = c.ref_id
  ) numbered
  WHERE numbered.id = a.id
  AND row_num_seq NOT IN (1, 13)
)
WHERE EXISTS (
  SELECT 1
  FROM (
    SELECT b.id, b.ref_id, b.ITEM, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY b.ref_id ORDER BY b.id) AS row_num_seq
    FROM test_delete_me b
    INNER JOIN (
      SELECT ref_id
      FROM test_delete_me
      WHERE status = 3
      GROUP BY ref_id
      HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN ITEM IS NULL THEN 1 END) > 2
    ) c ON b.ref_id = c.ref_id
  )  numbered
  WHERE numbered.id = a.id
  AND row_num_seq NOT IN (1, 13)
);

I need help optimizing this update statement to improve its performance significantly. Any suggestions or insights would be greatly appreciated!

Hi - please update your question with the EXPLAIN PLAN for the specific query you want help with (and make it clear which of the two queries in your question it refers to)

I think ref_id IN (...) does not require any GROUP BY clause. The values inside IN (...) do not have to be unique, it does not matter if a value appears multiple times.

Most likely it will not make much difference, but you can write simpler HAVING  COUNT(ITEM) > 2

Analytic functions (such as ROW_NUMBER()) can be very inefficient on large data sets - check your EXPLAIN PLAN.

Optimization would require knowledge of your data, your indexes, and the execution plan being used. Nobody can optimize SQL just by looking at it alone. But, you can usually position yourself well by avoiding certain constructs (like those nested EXISTS subqueries and joining the table to itself 5 times) and opting for others as an initial foundation. If I were doing this, I'd do something like this, which should not require indexes at all:
MERGE INTO test_delete_me tgt
USING (SELECT *
         FROM (SELECT /*+ parallel(4) */
                      ROWID row_id, id, ref_id, item,
                      COUNT(CASE WHEN status = 3 AND ITEM IS NULL THEN 1 END) OVER (PARTITION BY ref_id) cnt,
                      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ref_id ORDER BY id) AS row_num_seq
                 FROM test_delete_me)
        WHERE cnt > 2
          AND row_num_seq NOT IN (1, 13)) src
 ON (src.row_id = tgt.rowid)
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET tgt.item = src.row_num_seq - 1

I'd also double-check your (1,13) logic, it doesn't sound right that you'd treat 13 as special. If you mean first and last, you wouldn't want to assume that the last one is #13.
